# How to use a date range in a Cognos SQL Prompt Query

Tags: macros, prompt, cognos

I'm using a prompt query in Cognos to allow users to filter based on the past X number of days from the current date. How do I format the query for Teradata?

I've tried with and without `"#sq"` in my code and with and without `"integer"`as the format. When I hard code a number it works as well (i.e  day_date between (current_date - interval '6' day) and current_date).

`day_date between current_date - interval (#sq(prompt('Select_number_of_days', 'integer'))# )`
 day and current_date

The error message I receive is:

> Syntax error, expected something like a string or a Unicode character literal between the 'interval' keyword and '('.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: `[day_date] between current_date and _add_days(current_date, -1* ?DaysBack?)`.  Be sure to check the native SQL to ensure the current_date is being passed down to the database.  If it's not you can replace current_date with: `#timeStampMask($current_timestamp,'YYYY')#`